# Use MacBook Pro's trackpad to control ipad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, trackpad

Apps like [typeeto](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/typeeto-remote-bt-keyboard/id970502923?mt=12) use Bluetooth to link a MacBook Pro's keyboard to control an iPad. iPadOS 13.4.1 also supports using the Magic Trackpad or Magic Mouse on an iPad.

I'm wondering if there is any way to use a MacBook Pro's trackpad to control an iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but unfortunately you still have to wait.

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/06/macos-monterey-introduces-powerful-features-to-get-more-done/

This is a developer feature for now but it will be made public sometime this year.